# How to start bar from 1 instead of 0 in Vega Lite?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm plotting the diff time series `[1.1, 0.9, 1.2, ...]`.

And as the values are relative multipliers, the middle is 1 and not 0.

Is there a way to tell Vega Lite to start bar with 1?

So for the value `1.1` the bar will be `start: 1, end: 1.1` and for 0.9 it will be `start: 1, end: 0.9`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `y2` encoding with `datum` set to 1. For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAHvCAIIgA0IAnvAAwB0AnAL7mHEBCF1d9AHK3ZwQAYW404ARnqTBIIsIAi4+NIBMchSACiKuAxZt5xAGJ7pAZmYBdViAC2EAE4BrYgCNn3DADsAxgD2YACWPgDm8EKgUFQADhjEPgH2oajcAGbBGChgxER2EtFxCcIAjmgQPlDBMNWICZSZ2bnCNJRYfqgloGDJEKF4DABs5NIALLYFapHg0Gj2qsxLQA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": "A", "y": 0.9},
      {"x": "B", "y": 0.8},
      {"x": "C", "y": 1.1},
      {"x": "D", "y": 1.2},
      {"x": "E", "y": 0.9},
      {"x": "F", "y": 1.3}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "x"},
    "y": {
      "type": "quantitative",
      "field": "y",
      "scale": {"domain": [0.6, 1.4]}
    },
    "y2": {"datum": 1}
  }
}
```

[image]